How would I update a nested model that is defined as a list?
I have the following model defined.  Its derived from a boto3 IAM response:
class UserInfo(BaseModel):
    UserName: str
    AccessKeyId: str
    Status: str
    CreateDate: datetime.datetime


class HTTPHeaders(BaseModel):
    server: str
    date: str
    x_amzn_requestid: str = Field(..., alias='x-amzn-requestid')


class ResponseMetadata(BaseModel):
    RequestId: str
    HTTPStatusCode: int
    HTTPHeaders: HTTPHeaders
    RetryAttempts: int


class ListAccessKeysModel(BaseModel):
    AccessKeyMetadata: List[UserInfo]
    IsTruncated: bool
    ResponseMetadata: ResponseMetadata

I've tried everything, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to update the 'CreateDate' field, in the UserInfo model.  How would I go about doing that?  Really, I'm just trying to modify the date for unit test purposes.  Thank you!
I've tried the following, but its not working as it just gives back the same data (CreatedDate not changed).
list_access_keys = list_access_keys_model.model_copy(update={'AccessKeyMetaData': [{'CreateDate': create_date}]})

U need to call userinfo class and inside it add date part

Yea, why does list_access_keys_model.AccessKeyMetadata[0].CreateDate = ... not work?

@Plagon Ugh, actually that does work. :-P  Not sure why I was overthinking this.  Thank you!
